# Show two correlation coefficients on pairgrid plot with hue (categorical variable) - seaborn python

Tags: python, seaborn

I found a function to compute a correlation coefficient and then add it to a pair plot (shown below). My issue is that when I run a pairplot with hue (a categorical variable) the correlation coefficients for the two groups show on top of each other.

[this is how the plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZao1.png)

This is my graph code (which shows the correlation coefficient between climate change attitude and Peak as a function of "sea ice direction" on top of each other):

```
`g = sns.PairGrid(df, vars = ['OverallClimateChangeAttitude', 'Peak'], 
hue="IV_SeaIceChangeDirection")
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, s=10)
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
g.map_lower(corrfunc)`
```

Here is the correlation function:

```
`def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r),
            xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)`
```

Any help very MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that your correlation function specifies the exact location where the annotation should be placed and this location is `(.1, .9)` - the same for both hues. You need to somehow choose different locations for different categories of data. I thought of two ways to do this:

- either count how many annotations are already in the axes to position the new one below the rest
- or predefine positions for each `hue` value by hand and use `kws['label']` to choose which one to take.

See the `corrfunc` code below for both options. I made a plot with the rest of your code and an example dataset. I also added label text to annotations because otherwise I can't tell which correlation coefficient is which.

```
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    # count how many annotations are already present
    n = len([c for c in ax.get_children() if 
                  isinstance(c, matplotlib.text.Annotation)])
    pos = (.1, .9 - .1*n)
    # or make positions for every label by hand
    pos = (.1, .9) if kws['label'] == 'Yes' else (.1,.8)

    ax.annotate("{}: r = {:.2f}".format(kws['label'],r),
                xy=pos, xycoords=ax.transAxes)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.PairGrid(data = tips, vars = ['tip', 'total_bill'], hue="smoker", size=4)
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, s=10)
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
g.map_lower(corrfunc)
g.add_legend()
```

The result:

[image: seaborn pairplot with annotations]

Comment: Both solution work perfectly well! I chose the 1st solution because it is more automatic and so elegant! I am now trying to adapt the function to fit the correlation coefficient in a pair plot - but without success...   `g = sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=["Probability", "Vagueness"], y_vars=["Climate change attitude"],
             hue="Sea ice change", kind="reg",  markers=["v", "^"] g.map_lower(corrfunc2))` I guess it is because the variables are split in X and Y variables?

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what exactly went wrong. But I think there might be some confusion as to which subplots should by affected by `map_lower` when there's only two of them. I'd suggest trying other mappings.